# Detect controller input in VRTK

Tags: vrtk

I'm kind of new to this so sorry if I'm writing in the wrong place - let me know and I'll move / delete this comment.

I'm currently having issues detecting controller input while using VRTK.

For example, when I have a collision between two objects, I want to be able to detect what buttons are being pressed on the controllers but can't seem to work out how I can do this.

Also, I have implemented the Interact Use functionality but I'm struggling to work out how to make two buttons do different actions.

*For example:*

> once I grab an object with the simple pointer I want one button to
>   bring the object closer and another to move it away, but I've only
>   managed to implement one or the other.

---

Any suggestions? I've looked everywhere in the docs, examples and Google and can't seem to find anything. Any help would be MUCH appreciated! Pulling my hair out here!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could utilise the `Grabbed`method on the InteractableObject: https://vrtoolkit.readme.io/docs/vrtk_interactableobject#section-grabbed-1

Or you could use the `ControllerGrabInteractableObject` event on The InteractGrab script: https://vrtoolkit.readme.io/docs/vrtk_interactgrab#section-class-events

Or you could have an Update routine and check the `grabbed` status on the controller doing `GetGrabbedObject() != null` (which checks to see if the controller has an object grabbed if it's null then one isn't grabbed).

Then you can use the ControllerEvents button bools to do something on a button press. So a script with this in that sits on the controller script alias gameobject next to the interact grab script:

```
void Update() {
  if (GetComponent<VRTK_InteractGrab>().GetGrabbedObject != null) {
    var controllerEvents = GetComponent<VRTK_ControllerEvents>();
    if (controllerEvents.IsButtonPressed(VRTK_ControllerEvents.ButtonAlias.Trigger_Press) {
        //Do something on trigger press
    }

    if (controllerEvents.IsButtonPressed(VRTK_ControllerEvents.ButtonAlias.Grip_Press) {
        //Do something on grip press
    }
  }
}
```